# Passport.js - OAuth logins (Google, Facebook etc) - how to store state during redirects?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

Using Passport and Express I have Google & Facebook logins working pretty well.

These logins redirect to Google/FB etc and then redirect back to a URL on my server (say /login/success).

I would like to persist some state from pre-login so that it's available on the final redirect to /login/success

Passport doesn't seem to have any direct way of doing this (I could be wrong?)

The solution I have right now is to store stuff in the session like this:

```
app.get("/login/google", myStoreStuffInSessionMiddleware, passport.authenticate("google"));

app.get("/login/success", function (req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate("google", function (err, user) {

      getMyStuffFromSession(req.session)

      req.login(.....)
...
```

This seems to work OK but using a session relies on the login service keeping the cookie header which (I guess) they could choose not to.

So, I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I am using code authorization model with popup uxmode, where the authorization is done in popup window and redirected back to the client web, so I am not losing to state and react application flow. https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model.

Comment: @Fide interesting. I don't see anything about popups in Passport but maybe I can invoke it from a popup so it doesn't need to do anything. I'll see what happens.

Comment: Nono, it is not the job of server, but the frontend client! The frontend code invokes popup, where is the user login, and in case of successful login you receive a code from google to frontend, which one you in backend exchange for the access token.